# Jetpack Compose: Spacer vs Modifier.padding()

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

We can add a spacing between two components in compose through:

- `Spacer()`; and
- `Modifier.padding()` of the Component.

Is there any situation where one of those two ways is more desirable than the other?

Comment: I assume that `Spacer` creates a separate view instance in the hierarchy, while `Modifier.padding()` changes the bounds of the component, and so which you prefer depends on whether either of those two things is relevant to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compose Spacer vs view padding performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70199822/compose-spacer-vs-view-padding-performance)

Comment: Thanks for the linking that question but it is not 100% related to this one. I would like to know when to use which and why (having performance and also good practice in mind)

Answer (score 4):

Both **padding** and **Spacer** are essential layout utilities in Jetpack Compose, but their primary use cases differ. Whether you should use one over the other depends on the specific design scenario and your personal preference. Here are some guidelines to help you decide:

**Padding:**

- Use padding for adding space around the edges of a composable.
- It's more direct when you need space between a composable and its parent.
- For instance, if you want to add space around a Text element inside a Box, you'd likely use padding.

Syntax:

```
Text("Hello", modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
```

**Spacer:**

- Use Spacer when you need to add space between siblings inside a layout container such as Column or Row.
- It acts as an invisible composable just to take up space.
- It's especially helpful when you want to add space between two composables in a Row or Column without adjusting their individual paddings.

Syntax:

```
Column {
    Text("Hello")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
    Text("World")
}
```

If you're looking to adjust the space of an individual element relative to its container, padding can be more intuitive.
If you're looking to add space between elements in a sequence (inside a Row, Column, etc.), then Spacer is often clearer.
Performance:

Both are efficient and lightweight. From a performance perspective, there isn't a significant difference between them that you'd notice in regular use cases.
Ultimately, the best practice is to use the one that makes your code more readable and maintainable. In most scenarios, the choice between Spacer and padding will be clear based on the layout requirements.